# Get selected items from GetOpenFileName dialog including directories

Tags: c++, file, winapi, dialog

There is really no library that can provide sufficient file dialog functionality on multiple platforms (exclude portable-file-dialogs but it's still not enough for me), so I decided to write my own C++ library.

Now I am implementing the dialog on Windows before Vista, when there was no `IFileDialog` and accordingly there was no standard way to select folders (`SHBrowseForFolder` looks ugly and I'll never use it).

From the documentation, I found out that I can get the current selection if I specify a hook procedure and process `CDN_SELCHANGE in notify` event. However, the macros `CommDlg_OpenSave_GetSpec` and `CommDlg_OpenSave_GetFilePath` return only files list, when I need folders too. This is expected, but I don't know of any other method. In theory, I should get the `lst1` (list box with content according to documentation) descriptor and use `ListBox_GetSelCount` and other convenient macros. However, when I use the following code, the `filesBox` is NULL:

```cpp
HWND filesBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, ID_FILES_LISTBOX);
cout << "filesBox = " << filesBox << endl;
auto count = ListBox_GetSelCount(filesBox);
cout << "count = " << count << endl;
```

Somehow I learned to replace `hDlg` with `GetParent(hDlg)` and it really worked! `filesBox` is no longer NULL, but now `ListBox_GetSelCount` doesn't work. What should I do?

I know that there will definitely be someone who will ask for the full code, so I'll leave it here the code of the hook procedure:

```cpp
UINT_PTR CALLBACK HookProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (message == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        return true;
    }

    if (message == WM_NOTIFY) {
        auto pNotify = reinterpret_cast<OFNOTIFY*>(lParam);
        auto params = pNotify->lpOFN;
        auto code = pNotify->hdr.code;

        if (code == CDN_SELCHANGE)
        {
            HWND filesBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, ID_FILES_LISTBOX);
            cout << "filesBox = " << filesBox << endl;
            auto count = ListBox_GetSelCount(filesBox);
            cout << "count = " << count << endl;
        }
        else if (code == CDN_TYPECHANGE)
        {
            auto i = params->nFilterIndex - 1;
            auto filter = const_cast<LPTSTR>(params->lpstrFilter);
            CommDlg_OpenSave_SetDefExt(GetParent(hDlg), getExtensionFromFilter(i, filter));
        }
        else if (code == CDN_FILEOK)
        {
            /* Check if all files are in one folder */
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The file dialog since Windows 95 has used a listview, not a listbox, so try e.g. `ListView_GetItemCount` instead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Nothing changes. I'm testing the code on Windows 11. Could this be a source of problems?

Comment: Why are you testing code that targets XP on 11? You surely won't be using this code on vista and up?

Comment: `GetOpenFileName()` is just a legacy wrapper around `IFileOpenDialog` on modern Windows. You really need to test your code on an OS that you are actually targeting. In any case, "*`SHBrowseForFolder()` looks ugly and I'll never use it*" - unfortunately, that is the only standard dialog available for selecting folders on those old OS versions. Ugly or not, you should use it, since that is what users of those OS versions are going to expect. `GetOpenFileName()` simply can't return folders, only files. I don't think using a hook is going to help you with that.

Comment: @Remy is right.  Users expect file and folder selection to work in a certain way (which is why the common dialogs exist) and it would be most unwise to do something different.  I, for example, use a very fine open source graphics editor called gimp.  But it has a non-standard file picker and it drives me crazy every time I use it.

Comment: The ugliness of SHBrowseForFolder seems moot since nobody will see it because who is still running XP?